# undefined reference to a class variable inside a static library

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have liblib.a that has lib.h and lib.cpp:

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

namespace N1 {
namespace N2 {
class C1 {
    C1();
public:
    enum DAY { MONDAY, TUESDAY, END };
    struct DAY_PAIR {
        const int index;
        const int garbage;
        DAY_PAIR(int i, int g) : index(i), garbage(g) {};
    };

    static const DAY_PAIR MONDAY_PAIR;
    static const DAY_PAIR* PAIRS[END];
    static void init();
};
}
}

#endif

#include <iostream>
#include "lib.h"

namespace N1 {
namespace N2 {
const C1::DAY_PAIR C1::MONDAY_PAIR(MONDAY, 1234);
const C1::DAY_PAIR* PAIRS[] = {&C1::MONDAY_PAIR};
void C1::init() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
}
}
```

And I try to link my dummy program to liblib.a:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    N1::N2::C1::init();
    std::cout << N1::N2::C1::PAIRS[N1::N2::C1::MONDAY]->index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And g++ gives me:

```
/tmp/ccKKqDsT.o: In function `main':
/home/h/test/cpp/nested.cpp:7: undefined reference to `N1::N2::C1::PAIRS'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I don't create liblib.a and then try to compile all .cpp files into an executable.  It compiles fine.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit different -- the post you referred to miss the definition of the class variable.  I have already defined the class variable inside lib.cpp and compiled it into liblib.a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing class name before PAIRS in lib.cpp, so:

```
const C1::DAY_PAIR* C1::PAIRS[] = {&C1::MONDAY_PAIR};
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely overlooked it!

Answer (score 3):

There is problem in your .cpp file at line `const C1::DAY_PAIR* PAIRS[] = {&C1::MONDAY_PAIR};`

Should it be `const C1::DAY_PAIR* C1::PAIRS[] = {&C1::MONDAY_PAIR};`?

Comment: Thanks! Completely overlooked it!